# During string reversal extra character is added for array size less than 5 in c using jni

Tags: java-native-interface

I'm writing a basic string reversal program in c by getting the input from java through jni. I'm initialising the output array dynamically by getting the output of the input string. But the output always has an extra letter if the length of the string is less than 5. For example the output for "hello" is "ollehp". So how can I fix this?

This is my code.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_JavaTest_reversal(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring input)
{
        const char *str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, input, 0);
        const int length = (int)strlen(str);
        int l = length;
        char output[l];
        int j = length-1;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
        {
                output[j] = str[i];
                j--;
        }
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, input, str);
        printf("output %s \n",output);
        return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, output);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to allocate space for a terminating null character and set it to 0.

Comment: So why there is no problem when the length is greater than 5?

Comment: Well, the behavior is undefined, so anything can happen. The contents of the stack typically starts out filled with 0, but previous function calls leave stuff behind. When the string is short, it sits in memory that is non-zero; when it is longer it is placed in fresh, still zero memory.